# What cheeses make for good gifts?

Tags: cheese

Someone I know really likes cheese, so in lieu of any other ideas, and because there is a local market having a cheese event in the near future, I'm considering getting him cheese as a gift.

The trouble is, I'm not quite sure what cheeses make good/bad gifts, for example is it highly perishable, how much is an appropriate amount, which cheeses are actually impressive and worth pushing the boat out a bit for?

(I'm aware this isn't a perfect fit for this board, however of the Stack Exchange website this was the most appropriate)

Comment: OK, just thinking about how to answer this made my mouth start watering!

Comment: Unfortunately this pretty subjective -- perhaps [edit] to rephrase as good gifts in general for a cheese lover?

Comment: Take the advice of the stallholders at the event (on keeping qualities as well as style), and pay the extra for a nicely presented tasting assortment. That's usually an option at food events just before Christmas, where that's a big thing

Answer (score 3):

Don't; you don't know his taste.

Get him something related to the cheese instead like a small specialty knife (Girolle) or wood/slate platter or books.

If you want to get something edible, get some good honey, quince "cheese", chutneys or nuts.